# How to use HikariCP with JdbcTemplate in Springs MVC 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

I am new to Springs MVC and I tried to integrate HikariCP with JdbcTemplate. But got lot of errors any help, how to point JdbcTemplate to HikariCP DataSource.

in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
<property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
<property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
<property name="dataSourceClassName"       value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
<property name="dataSourceProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
        <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
        <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

 <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy- method="close">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
 </bean>
```

And in controller:

Controller
public class HandleWareHouse{

```
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}


@RequestMapping(value="/saveProduct_categories", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String insertPc(@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams){
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "INSERT INTO product_categories(name,code,des,grp_name) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {requestParams.get("pname"),requestParams.get("pcode"),requestParams.get("stext"),requestParams.get("pcategory")});
    return "sucess";
   }

 }
```

But getting error as shown below:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Answer (score 4):

I have used spring javaconfig to configure datasource and getting jdbctemplate. I think this is the best

```
@Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        private HikariDataSource dataSource() {
           final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
           ds.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
           ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
           ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"); ;
           ds.setUsername("username");
           ds.setPassword("password");
           return ds;
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {

        return new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    }
```

I hope this works well to you.

Answer (score 0):

The above code will give this error :
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle.

Use this :

```
   public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(snowflakeDriverClass);
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(snowflakeUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(snowflakeUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(snowflakePassword);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}
```